# Loop a Macro through each Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a macro that will perform a process on each column, up to a specific column "X".

Below is a macro I recorded and then some additional code I tried to paste in to get the desired result.

```
Sub ColumnFill2()
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
   Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))=0,"""",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))"

   Dim lngCol As Long
   Dim X As Long
   lngCol = ActiveCell.Column + 1

   For X = 1 To 57
      Cells(X + 1, lngCol) = X
   Next X
End Sub
```

I'm looking to have each column formatted with the included formula on each empty row (the spreadsheet is subtotaled).  Currently, it works on column 1 but then something is off.  I believe it's the starting point on the next column, which should be in Row 2 each time.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647151/excel-vba-loop-through-range-and-set-formula-in-each-cell)

Comment: Thank you!  I will try to incorporate this.