# Using input box to store unique values

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on some data from which I want to extract unique values from a column and storing them in an array and later using it for other calculations.

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range([E1], Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)))

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
Range("K1:K" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub
```

[The Data set is found here.](http://bit.ly/1KQtfia)
Now I want the code to take the input using an input box which column to search([E1] here) for unique values and where the output is stored ("K1:K" here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `InputBox` code with a variable to hold its value:

```
Dim col As String
Dim output_col As String
col = InputBox("Type the column letter to search in", "Data Input")
output_col = InputBox("Type the column letter to write results to", "Data Input")
```

And add some logic, e.g., if the column letter length is not `0`, process.

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Dim col As String
Dim output_col As String
col = InputBox("Type the column letter to search in", "Data Input")
output_col = InputBox("Type the column letter to write results to", "Data Input")
If Len(col) > 0 And Len(output_col) > 0 Then
  Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  X = Application.Transpose(Range(col & CStr(1), Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)))
  For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
  Next
  Range(output_col & CStr(1) & ":" & output_col & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked so well. I am new at excel vba. So, if you won't mind, can you tell me what you mean by process?

Comment: I mean perform the transposition, etc. Continue with the code execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question if you could help me with. Suppose I choose the result to be posted in 'K' column using inputbox, can I use output_col and Cstr to put some calculations in the next column of my output.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Range.Offset()`: `Range(output_col & CStr(1) & ":" & output_col & objDict.Count).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)` - it will refer to the next column on the right. Or use `-1` to start adding data to the column on the left. [See reference here](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2021718&seqNum=8)

Comment: What I mean was suppose I want to write 'Appt' in next column on second row is there any way to write like this Cells(output_col+1 & Cstr(2)).value= Appt. Pardon if the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: No, you cannot sum "K" and `1` to get "L". You should use [`GetNextCol("K", 1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100531/3832970).

Comment: I am new on this and I don't know a lot about this. I want to ask some more questions but I can't move the conversation to chat. Is there any other way I can contact you?

Comment: A chat is available, just keep on writing here, BUT if you have other questions that are unrelated to this question (that I think is answered), you'd better perform your own research, or ask a new SO question *if it is unrelated to this one*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82857/discussion-between-curious-lad-and-stribizhev).